# Finding the sum of degree value of a node's neighbors

Tags: r, igraph, nearest-neighbor, degrees

I want to find neighbors of each node from a network, and then I'd like to calculate each neighbors degree. In the last step, I'd like to have the sum of the degree of each neighbor of a node. To that, I wrote the below lines:
This is a summary of what exactly I like to do:

```
result<-(1/degree(v))/sum(1/degree(neighbors of node 'v'))
```

and the `res` is the result of this value for each node, So it would be a numerical vector.

Suppose x is an igraph object:

```
edgelist <- read.table(text = "
A B
B C
C D
D E
C F
F G")

library(igraph)
x<- graph.data.frame(edgelist)
vids = V(x)

deg.inverse <- 1/degree(x)
  res <- double()

for (v in V(x)[vids]) {

  rad<-0

  for (vv in V(x)) {
    if (deg.inverse[vv] == Inf) {
      rad <- Inf
      break
    }

    else {

      rad <- rad + deg.inverse[vv]

      nb <- neighborhood(x, order = 1, V(x)[vids][vv])

    }

    res <- append(res, rad/sum(1/(degree(x)[nb[[1]][v]])))
  }
}
```

But, I faced error.

```
 Error in simple_vs_index(x, lazy_eval(args[[1]])) : 
  Unknown vertex selected
```

Any idea about it?

Comment: What error did you face?

Comment: Your code refers to `vids` but it is not defined in your code.

Comment: @G5W Your right. I added it.

Comment: I tried to make it more informative.

Comment: @JohnColeman I add the res value.

Comment: What is the point of `V(x)[vids]` rather than just `V(x)`? Since you defined `vids = V(x)` you seem to be writing `V(x)[V(x)]` which is very odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to use loops. Simply write a function which calculates what you want for a node and then use `sapply` to map it over `V(x)`:

```
library(igraph)

edgelist <- read.table(text = "
A B
                       B C
                       C D
                       D E
                       C F
                       F G")

x<- graph.data.frame(edgelist)

f <- function(v){
  (1/degree(x,v))/sum(1/degree(x,neighbors(x,v,'all')))
}

results <- sapply(V(x),f)
```

If this isn't the expected output, you would need to clarify just what the expected output is.

Comment: That was great. Thank you.